# Оптимизация кода для функций

Tags: android

У меня есть две функции, которые имеют практически схожие функции. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы оптимизировать этот код: написать схожую информацию для этих кнопок, а отдельно написать их отличительные свойства. Не совсем понимаю, как это сделать :).

Код:

```
ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void mainFunc(){
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams.setMargins(15,10,0,0);

    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                if (event.getRawX() + dX != 15) {
                    String s = "Alex";
                } else {
                    Intent int46 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, potato.class);
                    startActivity(int46);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                        lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX > 100){
                            view.setX(100);
                        }
                        if(event.getRawX() + dX < 15){
                            view.setX(15);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    });

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParamsDeleteBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 75);
    final ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    deleteButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    deleteButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    deleteButton.setLayoutParams(imageParamsDeleteBtn);
    deleteButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageParamsDeleteBtn.setMargins(50,40,0,0);
    mainLayout.addView(deleteButton);

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void potatoFunc() {
    ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    mainFunc();
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.product);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 25);
    editor.apply();
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void ogyrecFunc() {
    ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    mainFunc();
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ogyrecproduct);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 26);
    editor.apply();

}
```

mainFunc() - это общая функция, в которой содержатся данный, одинаковые для кнопок.
В potatoFunc() и в ogyrecFunc я добавил отличительные свойства.
 Теперь проблема состоит в том, что potatoFunc и oryrecFunc не читает, что находится в mainFunc, и подчёркивает imageView и mainLayout красным

Comment: А если подключить if/else?

Comment: @АртемИльинский Можно. Напишите, как это сделать, в ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Как то так, но сам проверь, и если я чего не увидел, добавь в соответствующий блок else if:

```
    private void vegetabels(boolean potato) {
LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
ImageButton imageView1 = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
imageView1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
imageView1.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams1);
imageView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
imageViewLayoutParams1.setMargins(15,10,0,0);


SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();




if(potato){
 imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.product);
editor.putInt("int", 25);
editor.apply();
}else{
editor.putInt("int", 26);
editor.apply();
 imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ogyrecproduct);
  imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent int461 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, ogyrec.class);
        startActivity(int461);
    }
});
 }


mainLayout.addView(imageView1);
```

}

Comment: Я думаю, что в else не надо добавлять ogyrec.

Comment: Если potato false - значит огурец

Comment: Нет, появление ogyrec зависит не от potato. Появление этих кнопок зависит от того, что введёт пользователь в EditText. Я сделал общую функцию для всех кнопок (в которой содержатся все одинаковые строчки), а в самих potato и ogyrec указал эту функцию, и отличительные свойства

Comment: если нужен огурец вызываешь vegetabels(false), если potato - vegetabels(true). Я сделал что ты просил.

Comment: Дополню свой вопрос

Comment: Теперь проблема состоит в другом, я написал её в вопросе

Comment: Вынеси переменные imageView и mainLayout  на уровень класса, и переминуй в огурце  imageView1 в imageView.

Comment: Подредактировал. Вот так должно быть?

Comment: Нет, не торопись. Почитай как объявить на уровне класса переменные, объяви их там, это просто. В потато и огурце убери строки "ImageButton imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);" и 
    "LinearLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);". В общей функции должно быть так "mainLayout = findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this)"И все может и заработает

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Вылетает приложение :(